# Can we have Django DateTimeField without timezone?

Tags: python, django, datetime, timezone

I have searched for this, and could not find any notes or tutorials.

Answer (score 24):

When you set `USE_TZ = True`(see [USE_TZ](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#std:setting-USE_TZ) for more info) in your settings, Django stores date and time information in UTC in the database otherwise it will store naive date time (date time without timezone).

The default `settings.py` file created by `django-admin startproject` includes `USE_TZ = True` for convenience.

So you have to set `USE_TZ = False` in your settings to avoid attaching timezone.

**NOTE:** However you cannot detach timezone only for a particular field. By following my suggestion above, you detach timezone from the entire database, so my guess is that it's better to use a CharField to store date without timezone.

You can try to override the default save handler and remove the timezone from DatetimeField before [saving](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/instances/#customizing-model-loading) the item into the database, by defining a save method for your model:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.datetime_field = self.datetime_field.replace(tzinfo=None)
    super(MyModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Which is the default, I believe.

Comment: @Andriy I want the date and time format this way    '2016-03-09 6:51:43.195486'

Comment: @Andriy I use query to insert into the table (not using django ORM) , any python functions would do for me.

Comment: @Sagar well, try to replace tz_info to None before saving it, `datetime_field = datetime_field.replace(tzinfo=None) `

Comment: @Andriy , This is working fine . But in database (postgresql) we get time stamp with timezone , that need to be like ' time stamp without timezone' , Anything under migrations only not from outside migrations

Comment: `save` should not return the object